# Como posso usar o IDLE com Anaconda?

Tags: linux, anaconda, idle-ide

Estou usando Anaconda por conter varias ferramentas para o desenvolvimento com python, mas me sinto limitado pois não consigo abrir usar as bibliotecas instaladas no Anaconda usando o IDLE.

O Anaconda tem uma versão do IDLE que abre ao executar `python -m idlelib` no terminal, mas é bem básica, deformada e limitada, porém as bibliotecas funcionam nela.

Quando executo: 
`import sys
print(sys.executable)`
 nessa ferramenta ela me retorna o path `/home/daniloeder/anaconda3/bin/python` mas já no IDLE normal me retorna `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

Não consigo fazer com que o path do IDLE seja o python do Anaconda.

Como faço pra usar o IDLE como ambiente integrado ao Anaconda?
Meu sistema operacional é o Linux Mint.